# How many n-dimensional closed submanifolds of $R^n$ have Euler characteristic 1?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

It is well-known that the closed $n$-ball has Euler characteristic $1$. Is it true that every closed (i.e., compact), connected $n$-dimensional submanifold (with boundary) of $\mathbb R^n$ having Euler characteristic $1$ must be diffeomorphic to the closed $n$-ball?

Comment: I guess "closed" means "without boundary" in usual English conventions.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Math Stack Exchange. However, if you want to ask there, make sure, include your own attempts to solve the problem. As a hint, think if you know any surfaces (besides the disk) which have Euler characteristic 1.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Take any finite simplicial complex $K$, find an $n$ for which $K$ embeds (piecewise linearly, even!) in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then for sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$, the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $K$ will be a compact manifold with boundary, and homotopy equivalent to $K$.  So there are plenty of examples.